# ¿Cómo selecciono la ultima fecha de asistencia de cada socio?

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener la última fecha de asistencia de cada `id_socio_general`, para poder filtrar por fechas de usuarios que no volvieron en diferentes lapsos de tiempo. Para esto necesito obtener la última fecha de asistencia de cada socio. Se que esto lo puedo hacer con:

```
SELECT * FROM socios_asistencia ORDER BY id_socios_asistencia DESC LIMIT 1
```

Y me da la última fecha de asistencia, pero necesito la última fecha de asistencia de todos los `id_socio_general`.

Esta es la consulta que se acerca a lo que quiero:

```
SELECT * from socios_asistencia WHERE DATE(creation_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Me muestra las fechas de 30 días atrás, pero no toma en cuenta si esa fue la última vez que asistió.

Entonces quisiera saber si hay forma de hacer eso :(

Gracias de antemano.

Adjunto captura de la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas agrupar por socio y usar `MAX` asi:

```
SELECT MAX(fecha_asistencia), id_socio_general 
FROM socios_asistencia 
GROUP BY id_socio_general;
```

Comment: Finalmente lo deje asi: SELECT MAX(creation_date) creation_date, id_socio_general FROM socios_asistencia group by id_socio_general HAVING MAX(DATE(creation_date)) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL ? DAY) y parece funcionar muchisimas gracias :)